# kendo UI Select area and zoom in selected

Tags: charts, kendo-ui, zooming

I am working on Kendo UI charts.
I want to develop simple chart that allows me to select area and zoom in selected part of the chart.
I could not find it in Kendo UI charts, however its already available in high chart. please have a look here.

```js
$(function () {
    $.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=usdeur.json&callback=?', function (data) {

        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                zoomType: 'x'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'USD to EUR exchange rate over time'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: document.ontouchstart === undefined ?
                        'Click and drag in the plot area to zoom in' : 'Pinch the chart to zoom in'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime'
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Exchange rate'
                }
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            plotOptions: {
                area: {
                    fillColor: {
                        linearGradient: {
                            x1: 0,
                            y1: 0,
                            x2: 0,
                            y2: 1
                        },
                        stops: [
                            [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
                            [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
                        ]
                    },
                    marker: {
                        radius: 2
                    },
                    lineWidth: 1,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            lineWidth: 1
                        }
                    },
                    threshold: null
                }
            },

            series: [{
                type: 'area',
                name: 'USD to EUR',
                data: data
            }]
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

I want to know, Can I do the same "select on drag" and "zoom selected area" of the chart?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is planned for the upcoming Q3 release:

http://www.telerik.com/support/whats-new/kendo-ui/roadmap

> Chart
>
> The Chart will add the highly anticipated scrolling & zooming
>   functionality. Users will be able to scroll and zoom on both desktop
>   and mobile devices—with mouse region selection and pinch gestures
>   respectively.

Comment: I see, Actually I am forced to work with Kendo JS. So, Is it possible (Custom will be fine) in kendo. I tried a lot, but didnt get it yet. Please help... Thank you

Comment: http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/EfORA Zoom with mousewheel and pan by dragging right/left. You can also use the stock chart to make normal charts with a navigator pane: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/financial/index